# Does Ubuntu 16.04 support intel 5300 wireless card?

Tags: wireless, intel, pcie

I used the Intel® Wireless WiFi Link 5300AGN card in my desktop, this wireless card transfer miniPCI to PCIE. Does the ubuntu support this type interface 5300AGN wireless card?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have one in my Lenovo T420 and it works just fine.